# How do I fix the uploading error in aptana studios: parent path doesn't exist

Tags: web

I have a quick question. I've been trying to upload my website to blue-host, but every time I try, it says that parent path doesn't exist, is there a way I can change the parent path so the uploads work

Thx,

willmonferno

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to file permissions, you don't have write access, try updating file owner or file permissions.

I'm guessing you on some type of linux system, so you either need a chown (change owner) shell command or a chmod command (change file permissions) on the parent folder

try:

## sudo chmod -R 777 {YOUR_PARENT_FOLDER}

This will recursively change this and all other files and folders below it in the file tree to allow everything. I would change it once you're in a production environment.